# Validate ClickOnce hash

Tags: validation, hash, msbuild, clickonce

I need to validate the hashcode when building a ClickOnce package - Any way to do this without installing it first? Ideally I would do it in my MSBuild script, right after I have created the package. It doesn't seem that Mage.exe has this ability.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could sign manually by using mage.exe from the Framework tools, there is an cli and an gui version of mage available. I've used the commandline tool for resigning packages while build and it works great, I think the cli should provide a way to validate hashs.

But btw. if you change any file you have to resign the entire package.

Comment: My intend is not to alter the package after I have published it. We've been having problems with our msbuild script the a hash mismatch when we install the packages. The problem has something to do with how and when we compile and when we package (need to create 12 different packages so far). The hash verification is a safety measurement, to ensure that no invalid packages are deployed to our accepttest environment.